# CMS.Ecommerce.IAddressExtensions obsolete

Tags: kentico

I'm porting some code over from a Kentico 8.2 build to a Kentico 11 website.  One of the snippets that I am migrating makes use of a `CMS.Ecommerce.IAddressExtensions` extension method `public static string GetStateCode(this IAddress address)`.

When I moved this over to my Kentico 11 build, Visual Studio finds that this extension method no longer exists: `IAddress does not contain a definition for GetStateCode and no extension method could be found.`.  I poked around the Object Viewer for the CMS.Ecommerce DLL, and sure enough, no `IAddressExtensions` class is present.

Is there a workaround to look up the state code for a given address in Kentico 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, Kentico has removed the `IAddressExtensions` class when upgrading from version 10 to 11. Here is the page for the [API change](https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-11/25600).

Based on my understanding, you will instead need to use the `StateInfoProvider` as below.

```
IAddress someAddress = /* snip */;
var stateInfo = StateInfoProvider.GetStateInfo(someAddress.AddressStateID);
var stateCode = stateInfo.StateCode;
```

You can then take this same logic and move it into your own extension class.

```
public static class IAddressExtensions
{
    public static string GetStateCode(this IAddress address)
    {
        var stateInfo = StateInfoProvider.GetStateInfo(address.AddressStateID);
        return stateInfo.StateCode;
    }
}
```